# Sending data from Lua script to a C# application

Tags: c#, lua

I'd like to be able to send some arbitrary information (just a string would be enough for what I need) from a Lua script that is running to a C# application that I've written.

In my situation, the Lua script is monitoring another program (that I don't have the source code to) for changes and then I wish to be able to send events to my C# application that then deals with them.

Currently I'm doing this with a .txt file that the Lua script writes to and the C# application reads, but this is not exactly optimal as sometimes the file will be locked when the C# application attempts to read it (because Lua is writing to it at that moment)

What is a good method of communicating small amounts of data between Lua and C#?

Comment: The C# application could self-host a WCF service or HTTP service or a JSON service. Alternatively you could look into named pipes or even a direct TCP connection. I agree that the file solution will have locking issues but you could use an incremental file name convention. Then there are also older solutions like COM.

Comment: There appear to be very good ways to integrate LUA with, embed it in and communicate with c# according to google.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the swift and informative response, I'll see if I can find information on connecting to TCP with LUA, alternatively I could host a WCF service as you've suggested which shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: This smells like the Dwarf Fortress - DFHack - [any other 3rd party app] triad... am I near?

Comment: The whatnow? I tried to play Dwarf Fortress for a couple of weeks once and it was fun... This is actually for extracting data from an emulator that's going to be used to control things like stage lighting/video and audio playback/etc.